# Fusion Drive split after removing the SSD and HDD from a iMac with a broken power supply / logicboard

Tags: macos, hard-drive, unix, data-recovery, fusion-drive

Recently, my iMac just turned off and did not start anymore. After countless tries, I opened the iMac and removed the SSD and HHD (Fusion Drive) in the iMac in order to rescue my data. I am not really sure why the iMac just went black, but I am pretty sure the power supply or the logicboard broke, because of a short circuit.
I put the SSD and HDD in an external exclosure, hoping the Fusion Drive would show as normal. Sadly, disk utility showed the following:

[image]

When I run `diskutil list`, I get the following result:

[image]

Is there a way to recreate the Fusion Drive **without** loosing my data, filenames...?